# A slightly weird topology/physics question

Tags: differential-topology, physics

*Note: Being no expert in any area of topology, I might make some major errors in describing what I'm envisioning here.*

Imagine three-dimensional Cartesian space with any point $P$ in it represented as $(x,y,z)$. Now let there be a differentiable function $f(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) = z$. Let one $z$-value exist for every ordered pair $(x,y)$. Now, let there be two points $P_0(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $P_1(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ on the graph of $f$.

On to the physics part.

Now that we have established $f$, let a three-dimensional frictionless surface be modeled by $f$, with the force of gravity pulling toward the $-z$ direction. Let there be a sphere of arbitrarily small radius and arbitrary mass tangent to point $P_0$ on the surface that has a velocity vector $<dx_{sphere}/dt,dy_{sphere}/dt>$. For any point $P_1$, can we assign $dx_{sphere}/dt|_{t=0}$ and $dy_{sphere}/dt|_{t=0}$ such that the ball eventually becomes tangent to ("rolls over") $P_1$ after an arbitrary span of time? (Ignore air resistance.)

Comment: What does g have to do with anything?

Comment: @WilfRosenbaum To show a property of $f$.

Comment: Ok, I admit I am not following. It seems you assume some arbitrary function f, then define g in terms of f, and then conclude that f is differentiable. I don’t really see how that argument works. But regardless why not just assume f is differentiable to begin with?

Comment: @WilfRosenbaum I didn't know that you could just say $f$ is differentiable instead of saying that every cross-section of $f$ forms a differentiable function. Sorry about that.

Comment: Also, I just realized that one of the conditions I had in place for the problem can be removed, making it more general. Hopefully this helps?

Comment: So is the sphere moving only due to initial velocity and gravity, and we can use conservation of energy to describe the motion? An is the sphere allowed to leave the surface?

Comment: @Andrei Yes and yes.

Comment: Given the constraints of your problem, the answer is no. I can easily come up with a smooth surface with a hole in it, such that the sphere would necessarily jump over the hole.

Comment: @Andrei This violates the stipulation that one z-value must exist for every (x,y)... wait, shoot, I thought I put it in.

Comment: Why? I can make the hole have a finite depth. It does not matter, as long as the sphere will jump over it

Comment: @Andrei But how will you force the sphere to jump over said hole? After all, you can set the initial velocity vector to anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106304/discussion-between-cloudy7-and-andrei).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the constraints of your problem, the answer is no. Here is an example:

Let's create a surface that is independent of $y$, so we constrain our problem on the $xz$ curve. Say the particle starts from $(0,0)$. Then make the particle go up a "hill" with a height $h$, with a small slope. Now put a very narrow hill, say 10 times as high, at a short distance. If the sphere would have enough speed to go over the second hill, it would instead bounce back from the side of the hill 2. So any point on the other side of hill 2 are unavailable. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Correct! In fact, it can be shown that the conjecture is false for all forces of gravity $\frac{d^2z}{dt^2}$, because of the precise fact the ball can leave the surface.